# Negative values not displayed in Albatross Plot while and positive displayed in the negative correlation area

Tags: r, p-value

I am trying to generate an Albatross plot using the metap package 1.8 in R.

The main issue is that the plot doesn't display the 3 negative values contained in my object "pval".
No. cases it includes a range of 30 values up to 600 000

Here is the result I get when generating the plot which does not display the negative values at all while it distributes some positive values in the negative correlation section - by setting all the numbers in pval as positive the plot displays them all but still the negative correlation area shows several positive values.

[image]

```
library(metap) 

pval <- (pval=c(0.03, 0.7, 0.51, 0.22,  0.02, -0.819, -0.916, 0.22, 0.4, 0.78, 0.2, 0.46, 0.001, 0.1, 0.002, 0.41, -0.18, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.86, 0.84, 0.347, 0.74, 0.08, 0.98, 0.39, 0.43, 0.02, 0.69))
fit.m <- albatros(pval, ptrend$`No.Cases`, axes = list(xlimit = 0.001, ylimit = c(1,600000), 
                                                   lefttext = "Negative correlation", righttext = "Positive correlation"), 
              
              contours = list(type = "corr", contvals = c(0.05, 0.009, 0.005), ltys = 1:3), 
              plotpars = list(yscale = 1000, pchs = 23, cols = 'blue'), main = "Validity")
```

**Here is a list of the warnings I receive when running the code:**

```
1: In ytrans(axes$ylimit[1]) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
2: In ytrans(axes$ylimit[2]) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
3: **In xtrans(p) : NaNs produced**
4: In ytrans(n) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
5: In ytrans(ylabs) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
6: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
7: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
8: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
9: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
10: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
11: In ytrans(nvals) : Defaulting yscale to sqrt
```

Thanks in advance to everyone for the help!

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the original albatros() function, p-values with an absolute value > 0.5 are not expected. Values greater than this are used to code p-values for negative associations. This introduces an imprecision into the code as p-values will never get closer to the null than |p| = 0.5.
That said the following code will help with your problem. Note that you did not include the ncases list and I took the liberty of inventing some values.

```
pval <- c(0.03, 0.7, 0.51, 0.22,  0.02, -0.819, -0.916, 0.22, 0.4, 0.78, 0.2, 0.46, 0.001, 0.1, 0.002, 0.41, -0.18, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.86, 0.84, 0.347, 0.74, 0.08, 0.98, 0.39, 0.43, 0.02, 0.69)
pval_p <- pmin(0.5, abs(pval)) # Limit p <= 0.5
pval_n <- pmin(0.499, abs(pval)) # Limit -p <= 0.499
pval <- (sign_p < 0) * (1 - pval_n) + (sign_p > 0) * pval_p # Recalc to work with albatros

ncases <- ceiling(exp(rnorm(30,3.5,2))*10)
fit.m <- albatros(pval, ncases, axes = list(lefttext = "Negative correlation", righttext = "Positive correlation"), 
                  contours = list(type = "corr", contvals = c(0.05, 0.009, 0.005), ltys = 1:3), 
                  plotpars = list(yscale = "Classic", pchs = 23, cols = 'blue'), main = "Validity")
```